# How to shift the column values based on the difference with previous row in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe which looks like below:

```
      Name       width        height   breadth      
0       1         13          90       2    
1       2         101         45       1
2       3         78          6        1      
3       5         11          34       1
4       6         23          8        2
```

So like seen, the name is not in sequence. There are missing files in between.
I want to shift the column values of width and height one row below if the Name is in sequence. If not i want to populate the width and height of the row as NaN.

I tried the below code:

```
diff=data['Name'].diff()
```

And tried to do a group_by using this diff in value. But it did not work.

I am expecting a result like below:

```
       Name       width        height   breadth      
0       1         NaN         Nan       2   
1       2         13          90        1
2       3         101         45        1      
3       5         Nan         Nan       1
4       6         11          34        2
```

Comment: Adding `Nan` values that way you will lose some data and also change the correspondence between the name and the widh and height. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes that is right. Because that data of width and height belongs to the missing row sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper Series for groups by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and pass it to [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
diff = data['Name'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
data[['width','height']] = data.groupby(diff)['width','height'].shift()
print (data)
   Name  width  height  breadth
0     1    NaN     NaN        2
1     2   13.0    90.0        1
2     3  101.0    45.0        1
3     5    NaN     NaN        1
4     6   11.0    34.0        2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temporary dataframe to add the empty lines and shift the values:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'Name': np.arange(
    data.Name.min(), data.Name.max() + 1)}).merge(data, on='Name', how='left')

temp.iloc(axis=1)[1:] = temp.iloc(axis=1)[1:].shift()

result = pd.DataFrame(data.Name).merge(temp , on='Name')
```